# Generating relative paths with Jersey UriBuilder

Tags: java, jersey, uri

Using UriBuilder as follows:

```
UriBuilder.fromResource(My.class).path("resource").build().toString()
```

generates `/my/resource`.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell UriBuilder that I want to generate a relative path like so `my/resource`. This is useful in cases where I want to advertise resource URIs relative to the root URI (`/my/resource` being an absolute path and a relative URI to the root scheme + domain + port).

Does my question even make sense?